# How do I get the current rotation angle with jCanvas animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, jcanvas

I can't figure out how to get the current rotation angle of an arch in jCanvas.  `layer.rotate` only seems to provide me with the original setting of rotate, when I'd really like to change its behavior when it hits a certain angle.

I have an [example setup on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pgSc/1/) to demonstrate the problem.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this value  **$('#rot').val()**

```
while (i < 1000) {
        setTimeout(function() { rotate() }, 1000);
        alert( $('#rot').val());
        i += 1;
    }
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to set the value of ``#rot`` to the current rotation of the layer, not get it.

Answer (score 0):

The `animateLayer()` and `animateLayerGroup()` methods support the same alternate syntax as jQuery's `animate()` method, which allows for a `step` callback:

```
// Cache canvas element
var $canvas = $("canvas");

// Draw and animate
$canvas.drawArc({
  layer: true,
  name: 'arcy',
  fillStyle: "#000",
  x: 100, y: 100,
  radius: 50,
  start: 135, end: 45
});
$canvas.animateLayer('arcy', {
  rotate: 360
}, {
  // Use the step callback to run a function on every frame
  step: function(now, fx, layer) {
    console.log(layer.rotate);
  }
});
```